# Google Play Services with maven already added exception

Tags: java, android, maven, continuous-integration

I'm having trouble including Google Play Services in a Maven build. I've use the [android SDK deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to deploy an apklib for GPS and have added the following to my pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>7</version>
    </dependency>
```

This works for importing the library but the issue occurs when I try to build the project using Maven. I get the following error during the build process.

```
    [INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    [INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/UnusedStub;
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    [INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

I've been able to resolve the error by setting the scope on the jar or apklib to provided but this causes a class not found exception at runtime. What am I missing here? From everything I've read online this is all you should need to use GPS with Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out another dependency of mine was also pulling down Google Play Services. I'm using the Drive SDK in my application along with google-api-client-android which was the culprit. The frustrating part was that the groupId and artifactId for GPS was different in google-api-client-android than the ones generated using the Android SDK Deployer. The solution was to add the exclusion to the google-api-client-android dependency as follows.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.android.google-play-services</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```